# unable to convert 1715UTC to local/gmt type

Tags: java, date-formatting

I unable to convert 1715UTC to local/gmt type using java 
I was tried

```
  temptime= "1715UTC"                            
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm");
  simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(temptime);        
  time= Long.toString(myDate.getTime());
```

But I get java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1715"
please help me to sort out this

Comment: what will be the value for `5:15 AM`, is it `0515UTC` or `515UTC` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is wrong. You have a format of `HHmm` not `HH:mm`

Here is the code corrected

```
String temptime= "1715UTC";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(temptime);        
long time= Long.toString(myDate.getTime());
```

Here is an [ideone](http://ideone.com/gFg8R8) with a similar code show the result in a String format with the correct output (17:15).

Comment: its take garbage date  and I want only time from this string

Comment: @ashishshiwalkar Like I said ... I changed the result to be more readable here. Just use your code to get the date value. I have edited the answer since this wasn't clear ... PS : this is not _garbage date_  but a more specific format